# my project only compiles the older version of my project and not the newer version

Tags: visual-c++

I am working on a project and what is happening is when ever i try to compile my code it only compiles the old code and not any of the new code that i added even though i know that the new code is correct. It like my project is point to some old version and won't updated and compile the newer version of my project. i am using Visual studio 2012. does anyone know what maybe causing this and how to fix it. I have not really tried anything because i am not even sure whats going on, but i have tried cleaning and rebuilding my solution.

Comment: i have also notice after changing a few setting option; that when i build my project it give me a message says "this project is out of date" could this be the reason for my issue and if it is how to i get my project not to be out of date

Answer (score 0):

I think you are not saving the code again whenever you update it. It used to happen with me many times.

press **ctrl + shift + s** to save all.

Then press **F6** to build your solution.

Then **Run** it.

Hope this will help.